# How to access php script which is password protected and how to send the data using post method to it?

Tags: php

I want to access the php script which is password protected and how to send the data to it using post method For example login form

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<h3>Add entry</h3>
<p> Add another Article</p>
<form action="http://abc:abc123@www.sevaraam.com/sevaraam_RFID/Scripts/login.php" method = "post">
<label for="username">Username</label> <input type="username" id="username" name="username"><br /><br />
<label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="text" id="password" name="password" ><br /><br />

<button type = "submit">submit</button>
</form>
</html>
```

This code is not working when i put username and password in start of link and if i don't put the username and password then it is working properly but asking password mannual

Comment: use CURL with help of Oauth mechanism.

Comment: sorry can u explain me with example to program plz

Answer (score 0):

You should use cUrl for this.

By using setop to set user/password, you should be able to POST your form to the server

```
$data = array('username' => 'the_username', 'password' => 'some_secret');

$myForm = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($myForm, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"abc:abc123"); 
curl_setopt($myForm, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sevaraam.com/sevaraam_RFID/Scripts/login.php");
curl_setopt($myForm, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($myForm, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($myForm);
```

This is not the complete code.

Comment: Thank you For help Bjorne but i didn't get your answer properly i want to add the code in html code so that when we call to action method by submit button i m not getting how to use this code in html

Comment: Basically what you need to do is: 1. Have a page with your HTML form posting to a PHP. 2. Let the PHP file validate the form data and then do the curl scripting part. 3. Return HTML page to user which confirms  that the form was submitted.

Comment: I had a quick look at your site `sevaram.com/sevaraam_RFID/Scripts/login.php`. doesnt return any special authentication requests? I expected to get a 401 Authentication response when accessing theh login.php page?